# Не получается реализовать scrollview на Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview

Мне нужно реализовать функционал scrollview на Kivy. Я укажу ниже свой код. Код запускается без каких либо ошибок но выдает не тот результат. Прошу помочь. Цель: Нужно сделать так чтобы пользователь мог прокрутить экран и смог увидеть все кнопки. Желательно при этом еще и иметь возможность прокручивать бесконечно и вверх и вниз. Но пока что я застрял на самом первом этапе. Кнопки отображаются не правильно. Я также добавил скрин. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.size = (900, 600)
        self.window = GridLayout()
        self.window.cols = 1
        self.window.size_hint = (0.2, 0.6)
        self.window.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.6}
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
        self.button_1 = Button(text='1st button', background_color='#04D0F9')
        self.button_1.size_hint = (0.2, None)
        self.button_1.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        self.button_1.bind(on_press=self.ask1)
        self.window.add_widget(self.button_1)

        self.button_2 = Button(text='2nd button', background_color='#04D0F9')
        self.button_2.size_hint = (0.2, None)
        self.button_2.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        self.button_2.bind(on_press=self.ask2)
        self.window.add_widget(self.button_2)

        self.button_3 = Button(text='3rd button', background_color='#04D0F9')
        self.button_3.size_hint = (0.2, None)
        self.button_3.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        self.button_3.bind(on_press=self.ask3)
        self.window.add_widget(self.button_3)

        self.button_4 = Button(text='4th button', background_color='#04D0F9')
        self.button_4.size_hint = (0.2, None)
        self.button_4.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        self.button_4.bind(on_press=self.ask4)
        self.window.add_widget(self.button_4)

        self.button_5 = Button(text='5th button', background_color='#04D0F9')
        self.button_5.size_hint = (0.2, None)
        self.button_5.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        self.button_5.bind(on_press=self.ask5)
        self.window.add_widget(self.button_5)

        self.button_6 = Button(text='6th button', background_color='#04D0F9')
        self.button_6.size_hint = (0.2, None)
        self.button_6.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        self.button_6.bind(on_press=self.ask6)
        self.window.add_widget(self.button_6)

        self.some_words = Label(font_size='16', text='Win or Lose', color='white', 
halign='center')
        self.window.add_widget(self.some_words)
        base = [self.button_1, self.button_2, self.button_3, self.button_4, self.button_5, 
self.button_6]
        for i in base:
            btn = Button(text=str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=40)
            layout.add_widget(btn)
        root = ScrollView(size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400),
            pos_hint={'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.5})
        root.add_widget(layout)
        return root

    def ask1(self, instance):
        self.some_words.text = 'Test 1'

    def ask2(self, instance):
        self.some_words.text = 'Test 2'

    def ask3(self, instance):
        self.some_words.text = 'Test 3'

    def ask4(self, instance):
        self.some_words.text = 'Test 4'

    def ask5(self, instance):
        self.some_words.text = 'Test 5'

    def ask6(self, instance):
        self.some_words.text = 'Test 6'

        return self.window


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Дополнение:
Проблема заключается в том что отображается информация со скрина выше. Но вместо этого должен быть отображен текст который я заведомо передал в переменную. Например 1st button, 2nd button и т.д. Также внутри scrollview не передается и функционал который без scrollview работает корректно. Например при нажатии на 1st button нужно чтобы появился текст Test 1. В данный момент ни одна кнопка не реагирует на клик.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Чем вас не устраивает пример из официальной документации?](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html)

*Не много модифицированный пример:*

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.app import runTouchApp


def create_buttons()->list:
    return [Button(text=str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=40) for i in range(25)]


class ScrollViewExample(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        # Make sure the height is such that there is something to scroll.
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))

        self.some_words = Label(font_size='16', text='Win or Lose', color='white',
halign='center', size_hint_y=None, height=40)

        layout.add_widget(self.some_words)

        for button in create_buttons():
            button.bind(on_press=self.button_click_handler)
            layout.add_widget(button)

        root = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
        root.add_widget(layout)
        return root

    def button_click_handler(self, instance):
        # print(dir(instance))
        self.some_words.text = f"Нажата кнопка: {instance.text}"


ScrollViewExample().run()
```

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ.

Comment: Я как раз взял за основу код из официальной документации и подправил лишь некоторые вещи. Дело в том что в документации идёт перечисление чисел. Например указно 100 и цикл for перебирает все числа входящие в 100. Мой же код должен перебирать список или кортеж. И именно это и не работает. Он выдает мне 6 строк но при этом не правильно передаются значения этих 6 строк. Должно быть: 1st  button, 2nd button и т.д. Но как видно из скрина отображается совсем другое + кнопки не работают и при нажатии не выдают необходимый результат. Например:. Test 1 при нажатии на кнопку 1st button.

Comment: Александр, спасибо за помощь. Но у меня все еще не получается реализовать задуманное. Я использовал который вы опубликовали, но к сожалению даже этот код не дает возможность перебирать кнопки один за другим. В каком месте кода мне стоит указать список из 6 кнопок?

Comment: Скоро обновлю ответ

Comment: Я думаю этого достаточно

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вы мне очень помогли. Я просто изменил кое какие детали и смог начать перебирать переменные в кортеже. Поставил галочку на ваш ответ, но увы поднять ответ наверх не смог из за моей репутации меньше 15.